# JavaScript equivalent to "namespaceInputName"?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-fieldtype, javascript

Is there a JavaScript equivalent to [`namespaceInputName`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#namespaceInputName-detail)?

My fieldtype settings are doing some interesting JavaScript gymnastics. Part of the process involves **creating an array on the fly** (so when the fields are submitted, the array will be stored properly). Currently, it's working great using JS code like this:

```javascript
function(subfield, type, value) {
    var name = 'types[MyPlugin_MyFieldtype][dataArray][' + subfield + '][' + type + ']';
    var hidden = '<input type="hidden" name="' + name + '" value="' + value + '" />';
    // Then add that hidden field to the DOM
}
```

Here's where it gets interesting... This prefix works great as long as I'm building a normal field:

```
types[MyPlugin_MyFieldtype]
```

But, it stops working when I try to build my field *within a Matrix*. Because when my field is nested within a Matrix, the prefix **should** look something like this:

```
types[Matrix][blockTypes][4][fields]
```

Is there any way (in JavaScript) to automatically set that prefix properly?

Comment: I've actually found a **completely** different way to go about this... but I'll leave this question up in case anyone has a legitimate answer for it.